# How to draw a picture background in a PApplet in Java?

Tags: java

I want to run this code like this where is my err?

```
package impractice;
import processing.core.*;

public class MyPApplet extends PApplet {
    private String URL ="F://learn//python//imgages//microarray.jpg";
    private PImage backgroundImg;

    public void setup()
    {    
        size(200, 200);
        backgroundImg = loadImage(URL, "jpg");
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        backgroundImg.resize(200, 200);
        image(backgroundImg, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The error show `The file "F://learn//python//imgages//microarray.jpg" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch`
    Is to put this picture to the project 's folder or how what to do?

Comment: How to use processing?

Comment: Why are you using double slash (//) in String URL ? Should be one only I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For the loadImage() method to load your microarray.jpg correctly into PImage backgroundImg, the image must be located in the data directory of your project.

For example if your MyPApplet class is located in .../src/impractice/MyPApplet.java
then **your image should be located in
.../data/microarray.jpg**

Then you can just load it like:

```
backgroundImg = loadImage("microarray.jpg","jpg");
```

Or you can try loading an image hosted online, for example:

```
backgroundImg = loadImage("https://microbenotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Steps-Involved-in-cDNA-based-Microarray.jpeg")
```